# ERROR Exiting Kafka due to fatal exception (kafka.Kafka$)

Tags: apache-kafka

```
~/kafka$ bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/boitran/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.17.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/boitran/kafka/libs/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/boitran/kafka/libs/slf4j-reload4j-1.7.36.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
[2022-12-29 13:46:12,977] INFO Registered kafka:type=kafka.Log4jController MBean (kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$)
[2022-12-29 13:46:13,359] ERROR Exiting Kafka due to fatal exception (kafka.Kafka$)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.refArrayOps([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at kafka.Kafka$.getPropsFromArgs(Kafka.scala:43) ~[kafka_2.13-3.3.1.jar:?]
    at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:86) [kafka_2.13-3.3.1.jar:?]
    at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala) [kafka_2.13-3.3.1.jar:?]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Option.orNull(Lscala/$less$colon$less;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at kafka.utils.Exit$.exit(Exit.scala:28)
    at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:122)
    at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
```

I have install and start kafka with exactly following to apache site, but it's error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is common if you have a lower version of Scala installed on your computer. Either download Kafka 3.3.1-**2.12**, for example, or upgrade Scala